# JQuery popup.("open") not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, instagram

I'm trying to open a popup window as soon as my page gets load with the help of .ready() function
and below is the code within it.
But the function below is not giving any response.
Any other way to open jquery popups on page load??

```
if( access_token==""&&access_token==null)
                 {
$( "#popupDialog1" ).popup( "open" )
}
```

The above code is integrated for an android app to be devloped using phonegap,html5,javascript etc

Comment: how can access token be both `""` and `null` at the same time?

Comment: I tried to find the specifications of the `jQuery popup` function, but I havent found it. Are you sure that you are not trying to use `popup` instead `dialog`?

Comment: i want to use popup only please check out this link                                                        
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: to open the popup add an id at the `<a id="myPopup">` tag an then using `$("#myPopup").click()` you open it

Comment: it will work on click function but iwant the popup to be opened on page load

Comment: use the following code: `$(document).on('pageinit', function() {$("#myPopup").click() });`

Comment: I have tried out this too its not working

Comment: try to post your whole code

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `||` instead of `&&` beacuse a variable can't be `empty` **and** `null` in the same time

```
if( access_token=="" || access_token==null){
    $( "#popupDialog1" ).click();             //try with click()
}
```

Comment: Try to log the value of the `access_token` variable before the if

Comment: the concole shows following errror:
Error: no such method 'open' for dialog widget instance
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20140501/r20140417/show_ads_impl.js

Comment: What is the code that you have posted? I can't find the `popup` part.

Comment: It's right, you havent the `open` method for dialog, instead you must click on the `a` tag related to the popup

Comment: is there anyway to open a popup within javascript or even if data-role="dialog" how will i open it in javascript by using its id

Comment: gt this error now
Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Comment: "...a variable can't be empty and null [at] the same time" - Challenge accepted... `var empty = null;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in jQuery or jQueryUI, it's a jQueryMobile method.

So the problem you're currently facing probably have something to do with the fact that you didn't initialize the popup before.

Try this (use the two lines).

```
$( "#popupDialog1" ).popup();
$( "#popupDialog1" ).popup( "open" );
```

You can also play with this jsBin http://jsbin.com/laceboni/1/

Comment: checdk this out    http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that jQueryMobile got this method (BTW it is really similar to jQueryUI Dialog).

Comment: Can you please send me the link for jquery ui dialog for reference

Comment: The demo is here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/. The API documentation is here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: well im getting something as follow on console using above methods do you have any idea ?
Error: no such method 'open' for dialog widget instance
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.RIXl5bUHOTM.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AItRSTMEDqSOskXzfRGcYnvBrDh5RTKEFQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0

Comment: I don't know what you're trying but it seems that you're doing something wrong. The dialog widget of jQueryMobile don't have an 'open' method that's why you're getting this error and you shouldn't use this widget because it's deprecated in jQueryMobile 1.4.0.  
Secondly using jQueryMobile and jQueryUI in the same time seems impossible as they both define the dialog widget (for example).
Finally, why did you change from popup widget to dialog widget ?

Comment: the problem is solved...by me
the widget id popup only now the function is working

Answer (score 0):

Check the undefined for access_token.

```
access_token == undefined
```

And change the logical operator from **&&** to **||** as you are checking two values for same variable at same time.

```
if( access_token=="" || access_token==null || access_token==undefined)
{
     $( "#popupDialog1" ).popup( "open" )
}
```

Comment: Is debugger is entering in the loop or not? Could you check the value of access_token while debugging and let me know its value.

Comment: yes, it is entering the loop because im also performing some other operations within the same loop to show and hide a div that is working properly but popup function is not getting execute.

Comment: I know this is strange, but could you try with single quotes like .popup( 'open' )

Comment: And #popupDialog1 should be id of DIV of popup page? if not then try to replace it with DIV id. Like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/2fqfV/)

Comment: yes ihave done that too  #popupDialog1 is the name of the div and its not working with single quote